# Casting GTK Clutter Textures and normal ClutterTextures

Tags: c, gtk, textures, clutter

I'm having a problem sorting out the casting in some old clutter code, trying to bring it up to date. It has code like this:

```
static void image_init(CtkImage *image)
{
    priv->texture = clutter_texture_new ();
    ...
}

static void refresh_icon (CtkImage *image)
{
  CtkImagePrivate *priv = image->priv;
  gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf (CLUTTER_TEXTURE (priv->texture), priv->pixbuf, NULL);
}
```

This produces this compile time error:

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
/usr/include/clutter-gtk-1.0/clutter-gtk/gtk-clutter-texture.h:99:17: note: expected ‘struct GtkClutterTexture *’ but argument is of type ‘struct ClutterTexture *’
```

I thought that I could fix it by using GTK_CLUTTER_TEXTURE, this does compile, but there is run time errors and lack of pixbufs:

```
gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_CLUTTER_TEXTURE (texture), tiled, NULL);
```

Resulting in:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `ClutterTexture' to `GtkClutterTexture'

Clutter-Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf: assertion `GTK_CLUTTER_IS_TEXTURE (texture)' failed
```

What is going on, and why is this failing? and how can it be debugged?

Answer (score 1):

GtkClutterTexture is a sub-class of ClutterTexture; this means that you can use GtkClutterTexture with every function accepting a ClutterTexture, but you cannot use a ClutterTexture with methods taking a GtkClutterTexture.

in the example, you create the texture using clutter_texture_new(), and then you pass that pointer to gtk_clutter_texture_set_from_pixbuf(). you either create a GtkClutterTexture, or you use the clutter_texture_set_from_rgb_data() function to set the image data from a GdkPixbuf, using something like:

```
  clutter_texture_set_from_rgb_data (CLUTTER_TEXTURE (texture),
                                     gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf),
                                     gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha (pixbuf),
                                     gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf),
                                     gdk_pixbuf_get_height (pixbuf),
                                     gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride (pixbuf),
                                     gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha (pixbuf) ? 4 : 3,
                                     CLUTTER_TEXTURE_NONE,
                                     &gerror);
```

which is exactly what GtkClutterTexture.set_from_pixbuf() does.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an uninitialized `GtkClutterTexture *` pointer to the function, which contains only garbage. You need to create a `GtkClutterTexture` object using `gtk_clutter_texture_new()` before you can fill it with a pixbuf.

**EDIT:**
In your updated example you have a `clutter_texture_new()`. That's not the same as `gtk_clutter_texture_new()`, and so casting it with `GTK_CLUTTER_TEXTURE()` tries to cast it to a type which it's not, producing the runtime warning.

Comment: I didn't show it in the example code (apologies) but we do have a gtk_clutter_texture_new, it's attached to a private object so I didn't want to complicate the example. I've updated it.